# use egrep to get package name of android app

Tags: android, regex, grep, aapt

I am wanting to extract out the package name of my apk for a script.

I can list the package name with something like this

```
./aapt dump badging <apk.path> | grep package
```

The output looks like this

```
package: name='com.example.app' versionCode='' versionName='4.6.10' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2166767'
```

so I want to run the aapt command and it only return `com.example.app`

I figured it would be something like, but still returns everything.

```
./aapt dump badging <apk.path> | egrep package:\ name='(.*?)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by doing multiple greps and some regex. Below worked from me. Not sure if its the best way, but works.

`$ aapt dump badging <path.to.apk> | grep package | grep -Eo '[a-z]+\.\w+\.\w+'
$ com.example.app`

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` again:

```
grep -Po "(?<=name=')[^']*" file
```

This uses `P`erl regex to print `o`nly what comes after `name='` and up to the following `'`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
package: name='com.example.app' versionCode='' versionName='4.6.10' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2166767'
buuu
$ grep -Po "(?<=name=')[^']*" a
com.example.app
```

Comment: That didn't work for me but figured it out with multiple grep commands and a different regex

Comment: @deluded12ga then you can maybe post your solution as another answer so we can all learn from it!

Comment: THANK you it worked really well.